# TDD and Factory Pattern

Tags: java, unit-testing, tdd

I am new to TDD. I try to implement an application that reads a configuration from a file and do some things.

I have a conf element interface:

```
interface ConfElement{
    doSomething()
}
```

then I have a two ConcreteConfElement that implements `ConfElement`:

ConcreteConfElementA:

```
class ConcreteConfElementA implements ConfElement{
     private propA;

     doSomething()
}
```

ConcreteConfElementB:

```
class ConcreteConfElementB implements ConfElement{

     private propB;

     doSomething()
}
```

then I have a factory that create `ConcreteConfElementA` and `ConcreteConfElementB` read from `Configuration` object passed to factory;

```
ConfElementFactory(){
  public ConfElementFactory(Configuration conf)

  ConfElement createConf(){
     if(conf.hasElA){
         return new ConcreteConfElementA();
     }
     else{
         return new ConcreteConfElementB();
     }
  }
}
```

How can I test factory method ? Is it well designed for TDD?

Answer (score 2):

With TDD you need to write the tests first, before the production code. TDD encourages design patterns to emerge overtime, rather than straight away.

- Write a test for use case 1
- Implement enough code to pass this test (no interfaces!)
- Test Passes
- Write a test for use case 2
- Implement enough code to pass this test
- Test Passes
- Refactor to remove duplicate (hint: The Factory pattern emerges!)

This way the code is 100% tested and no need to worry of the pattern is testable or not. Refactoring is a key element of TDD.

Answer (score 1):

It should be relatively easy to test the conditional logic of your factory. 
Two tests could be:

1. Instantiate a `Configuration` object with `hasEla` to be true.  Instantiate Element factory with the test `Configuration` object and assert that an instance of `ConcreteConfElementA` has been returned.
2. Repeat step one but set `hasEla` to false, and assert that `ElementB` has been returned.

---

I believe this particular factory is testable, because it allows the caller to inject the `Configuration`.